# On android how to reroute audio from a2dp

Tags: android

I have a Samsung vibrant and I am connecting to to my car using bluetooth. In the samsung music app there is a button to route the audio to via bluetooth or via phone.

Anyone know how there were able create this functionality. I looked at the sdk and I see

> ROUTE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP
>
> This constant is deprecated. Do not
>   set audio routing directly, use
>   setSpeakerphoneOn(),
>   setBluetoothScoOn() methods instead.
>
> Routing audio output to bluetooth A2DP
>   Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)

but as you can see it is listed as "deprecated", i see the option for setBluetoothScoOn, but not an equivalent to for setting a2dp on.

My end goal would be to create a widget that allows me to turn on and off outing to the a2dp. So I can turn it on when I want to stream music and turn it off when I want to use navigator, but listen to music or the radio at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you are looking for: (not sure if this was available at the time of your question...)

```
setBluetoothA2dpOn();
```

But it's also deprecated.

My guess would be to use this instead:

```
audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
```

And to stop routing:

```
audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
```

audioManager is a instance of the AudioManager.

Here's a reference to AudioManager: [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothA2dpOn%28boolean%29)

Hope this helps, cheers