# Stream and Play audio from android application to any available Speaker like A2DP,Car speakers etc

Tags: android, audio-streaming, docking, bluetooth-sco

From my android application I want to stream audio to any available speaker like `A2DP` speaker ,`docking` speakers or `car` speaker.

for doing this I want to use Bluetooth connection and stream over Bluetooth connection...

I saw following links

[On android how to reroute audio from a2dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580411/on-android-how-to-reroute-audio-from-a2dp)

[setBluetoothA2dpOn (boolean on)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothA2dpOn%28boolean%29)

[Android 2.3: How do I switch from SCO to A2DP for a capable Bluetooth speaker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920643/android-2-3-how-do-i-switch-from-sco-to-a2dp-for-a-capable-bluetooth-speaker)

But everywhere I found the same .. i.e.

```
public void setBluetoothA2dpOn (boolean on)

This method is deprecated.
Do not use.
```

Please guide me on how to do this..Or suggest if it can be done using some other way..
Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT** :

PERMISSION in manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

CODE :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    scoSwitch = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    try {
        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jc_cm);
        mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.rp);
        amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        //amanager.setBluetoothA2dpOn(true);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onSCOswitch(View view){
    if (scoSwitch.isChecked()){
        amanager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
        amanager.startBluetoothSco();
        Log.d("Bluetooth", "SCO on");
        amanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    }
    else{
        amanager.stopBluetoothSco();
        amanager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
        amanager.setBluetoothA2dpOn(true);
        Log.d("Bluetooth", "SCO off");
        amanager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems do you face while using this documentation .. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothA2dp.html

Comment: @userSeven7s : the problem i am facing is I am unable to detect that other device is also A2DP or not and so problem buffering audio

Comment: paste some code you tried with...

Comment: @userSeven7s :please see edited question

Comment: Can you share example code for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i refer u this link please try this

> [Android: Playing sound over Sco Bluetooth headset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212783/android-playing-sound-over-sco-bluetooth-headset)
>
> [TTS output always going to A2DP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963461/tts-output-always-going-to-a2dp)

i thing this link can help u

Comment: i am accepting this answer but please explain me some more on this..coz still i am not clear on how to implement this

Comment: this answer should be explained...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of Bluetooth A2DP in a Service. You can refer this code and build your own.

[A2DP Bluetooth Service](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/server/BluetoothA2dpService.java.shtml)

Comment: but for this i have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>`in manifest